# Why won't Razer Naga Epic work with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, usb, keyboard, mouse

My son's Razer Naga Epic causes the keyboard to repeat keys and not recognize keystrokes on the latest Raspbian OS running on version B. Can anyone explain why? Is it a hardware or software problem?

Comment: As recantha says, it is probably not enough juice.  The pi's USB ports are limited to 150 mA -- see http://elinux.org/Rpi_Hardware#Power -- which is sub-standard.  You may need to use a powered USB hub and plug the pi and the keyboard into that.

Comment: @goldilocks 150mA limits were lifted like a year ago, current boards allow you to get as much juice as your power supply can provide, until you trip the 1.1A polyfuse.

Comment: @lenik That page does say the polyfuses were removed "after August 25, 2012" -- I've only had mine about 6 months, and was convinced I had them since regardless of the power supply (up to 3.7 mA) the usb ports still don't put out properly.  However, looking at this picture: http://i.imgur.com/GuxsJ.png I don't have the polyfuses, so...some other factor?

Comment: This happens with a powered hub...

Comment: It may not be the keyboard that is hungry. Are there other things plugged in?

Answer (score 3):

Try a more powerful power supply. Keyboard repeats generally indicate a lack of power is being provided to the Pi.

Comment: I've noticed this, to an extent, if I run a keyboard directly from the pi's USB.  I don't think a larger power supply will necessarily help, as the pi's USB is limited to 150 mA anyway. It's fine if I use a powered USB hub and plug into that.

Comment: That was my first guess, so I bought a powered USB hub. Same problem. :-(